# PHP session system script reloads page without message

Tags: php, database

I'm totally new with PHP. I am building a PHP login system with session. The idea is that the user enters their username and password. Then they are redirected to a page that is locked, which links to other locked pages. Locked pages have a script that checks if a session is started. If not, the user is redirected to the login page. The issue that I'm facing is that the system basically is not working-no errors, no alert messages, which I put for debug purposes, nothing that indicates that the script is functioning. The only thing that can be considered is that the login form refreshes the page but I still expect to see an alert box just after the code executing.

**This is my login script(index.php)(totally not copy-pasted from random tutorial site)(Live url: http://daaseed.com/Player/):**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>
<?php
// Always start this first
session_start();

if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['username'] ) && isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {
        // Getting submitted user data from database
        $con = new mysqli("sfconsul.dot5hostingmysql.com ", "Nasko", "Nasko", "Nasko");
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Nasko WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $user = $result->fetch_object();

        // Verify user password and set $_SESSION
        if ( password_verify( $_POST['password'], $user->password ) ) {


            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->ID;
        }


        if ($con->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
alert("Hello World");
    }
}
?>
```

**This is the verifying code that checks if a session is set or not:**

```
<?php
// You'd put this code at the top of any "protected" page you create

// Always start this first
session_start();

if ( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ) {
    // Grab user data from the database using the user_id
    // Let them access the "logged in only" pages
    alert("Done");
} else {
    // Redirect them to the login page
    header("Location: http://daaseed.com/Player/");
}
```

[This is the screenshot from the login page after entering data and pressing the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLTQV.png)

The locked page shows the content without checking for session (based on my opinion since not alert box is displayed).

As you can see there is some issue or issues with the code that I cannot find the solution to. How to make the above code work successfully?

Comment: Welcome to php! Something that will help you figure out these types of issues 10x faster, and learn 10x faster: use an IDE that allows step-through debugging. This means you can walk through the code, line by line as it is running, and examine the values of variables, see exactly where the code is going, etc. Phpstorm IDE is a popular option, and XDebug is a popular tool for doing this debugging

Comment: `session_start()` *must* be before any output on your page. It clearly is not.

Answer (score -2):

Edit b/c I didn't see `session_start()` calls:

Chances are the problem lies either in the parameter binding for $stmt, or the `fetch_object()`. You'd probably want to do `fetch_assoc_array()` instead, then reference `$user['password']`. Can you try that, or otherwise echo the `get_result()` object and let us know what it is?